# Why data existing in model cannot be displayed in UILabel

Tags: swift, combine

**Question:**

*I can't see the `km: Optional(33300)` data coming to the model on the UILabel, why? For example, when I select the Audi vehicle, I can see the `km`, but when I select the BMW vehicle, I cannot see the `km` value on the UILabel, why?*

When I click on Cell, I move the data about the car to the detail page with combine.You can see the console output just below the code.

**I can see the `km` of other cars but not just one car's `km`. Why is that ?**

**didSelectRowAt:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let carDetailVC = CarDetailViewController()
        carListViewModel.$cars
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { cars in
                carDetailVC.carDetailViewModel.carSubject
                    .send(cars[indexPath.row])
                print("Cell: \(cars[indexPath.row])") // PRINT
            }
            .store(in: &anyCancelable)
        carListTableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        navigationController?.pushViewController(carDetailVC, animated: true)
    }
```

**Console Output:**

```
Cell: Car(brand: Optional("BMW"), features: Optional(CarList.CarFeatures(model: Optional("SERIES 3"), km: Optional(33300), year: nil, price: Optional(400000), image: Optional("http://dreamsandbytes.com/carimages/carimage.jpeg"), gearType: nil, fuelType: nil, carVersion: Optional("2.0 320D AUTO"))))
```

As you can see in the console output, `km: Optional(33300)` data is displayed.

Now let's go to the ViewModel page of the Detail Page where we are moving the data.

**CarDetailViewModel:**

I printed the Car data coming to this page to the Console output again. You can see the console output below the code

```
class CarDetailViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published private(set) var carDetail: Car?
    
    private var anyCancellable = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    var carSubject = PassthroughSubject<Car, Never>()
    
    func prepareCarDetail() {
        carSubject
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink {[weak self] car in
                self?.carDetail = car
                print("Car: \(car)") // PRINT
            }
            .store(in: &anyCancellable)
    }
}
```

**Console Output:**

```
Car: Car(brand: Optional("BMW"), features: Optional(CarList.CarFeatures(model: Optional("SERIES 3"), km: Optional(33300), year: nil, price: Optional(400000), image: Optional("http://dreamsandbytes.com/carimages/carimage.jpeg"), gearType: nil, fuelType: nil, carVersion: Optional("2.0 320D AUTO"))))
```

Here you can see the `km: Optional(33300)` data. However, I cannot see this data on the Label.

**I can see the `km` of other cars but not just one car's `km`. Why is that ?**

**DetailViewController:**

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    
    carDetailViewModel.prepareCarDetail()
    carDetailViewModel.$carDetail
        .sink {[weak self] car in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            self.assignmentDataToUI()
            self.prepareUIAnchor()
        }
        .store(in: &anyCancelable)
    
    
}

func assignmentDataToUI() {
    if let image = carDetailViewModel.carDetail?.features?.image { imageView.loadImage(url: image) } else { imageView.image = nil }
    if let brand = carDetailViewModel.carDetail?.brand { brandLabel.text = brand } else { brandLabel.text = "No Data" }
    if let model = carDetailViewModel.carDetail?.features?.model { modelLabel.text = model } else { modelLabel.text = "No Data" }
    if let km = carDetailViewModel.carDetail?.features?.km { kmLabel.text = "\(km)km" } else { kmLabel.text = "No Data" }
    if let year = carDetailViewModel.carDetail?.features?.year { yearLabel.text = "\(year)" } else { kmLabel.text = "No Data" }
    if let version = carDetailViewModel.carDetail?.features?.carVersion { versionLabel.text = version } else { versionLabel.text = "No Data"}
    if let gearType = carDetailViewModel.carDetail?.features?.gearType { gearTypeLabel.text = gearType } else { gearTypeLabel.text = "No Data" }
    if let fuelType = carDetailViewModel.carDetail?.features?.fuelType { fuelTypeLabel.text = fuelType } else { fuelTypeLabel.text = "No Data"}
    if let price = carDetailViewModel.carDetail?.features?.price { priceLabel.text = "\(price)" } else { priceLabel.text = "No Data" }
}
```

Comment: Did you try debugging and check what value has "carDetailViewModel.carDetail?.features?.km" inside "assignmentDataToUI"? And what do you mean you can't see km with given car? What text "kmLabel" has?

Comment: kmLabel = 23km on Audi vehicle but
BMW = nil

Comment: What is BMW = nil? Is it features.km value inside assignmentDataToUI? Is it the text on your label? You said you "can't see the km: Optional(33300)" in label, so what do you instead of this?

Comment: sorry sir. Audi -> km: Optional(33300)... BMW -> km: nil(No Data)

You can't see my console code ?